# Apache Airflow - AWS MFA Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I've been running [Airflow using helm chart](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow).
The object of airflow is to invoke AWS Batch Job in the DAGs like below.

```py
batch = AWSBatchOperator(
    task_id='batch',
    job_name='my-job',
    job_definition='arn:aws:batch:my-job-def',
    job_queue='arn:aws:batch:my-job-queue',
    overrides={
        'command': ["echo", "hello"]
    },
    array_properties={},
    parameters={},
    region_name='my-region',
    dag=dag
)
```

When I invoke this command, task fails with the log below.

```
[2020-12-01 08:30:11,642] {awsbatch_operator.py:150} INFO - AWS Batch Job has failed executed
[2020-12-01 08:30:11,660] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - Unable to locate credentials
```

This seems reasonable because our AWS policy forces users to login with MFA to do something in the AWS.

**How can I define Login these information(such as aws_access_key, secret, etc) onto above environemnt?** Should it be defined in helm chart's values.yaml or AirFlow UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you are running airflow on AWS, you should be able to attach an IAM role to the instance (EC2), tasks (ECS) or pod (EKS) so that credentials are not taken into account but rather the IAM role attached.

Also, AWS has a managed airflow service: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow-mwaa/

Comment: I'm not running airflow on AWS but on independent K8s cluster. Can I attach an IAM role in this case as well?
I really want to use MWAA but not in service in my region(ap-northeast-2) so far :(

Comment: Haven't used it myself. I'd say you might need to put `.aws/credentials` via k8s secrets.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've created a configmap from my local files under ~/.aws and mounted it to a pod. Confirmed it has been successfully applied. k8s secret would've been a better solution though. Now I'm trying to use IAM Role :-)